# MVC 5, [HttpPpost] Create method: Bind(Include = "List of Properties...") modifier - intended use?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Can someone shed some light on the use of the 'Bind' modifier in the following method signature?

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "List of model propertires.....")] MyModel model)
    {
    }
```

Can I use it to bind the posted values to a different model than the one I built the view with?

Thanks.

Comment: By default all properties of your model will be bound. `[Bind(Include=..)` allows you to specify a subset of the model properties to bind and is used to prevent mass asignment. Refer [6 Ways To Avoid Mass Assignment in ASP.NET MVC](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/11/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx). It has nothing to do with binding to a different model. If your view uses AModel but you post back to BModel, BModel properties will only be bound where the name of that property matches the name of a property in AModel

Comment: Thanks. I will certainly read the article you mentioned. My intention is to avoid properties that were needed by the view model but are not part of the actual data that I am going to insert / update in the database.

Comment: I read the Scott's article. I am glad you mentioned it. I now know the nature of the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use the Bind to bind the values to a different model.  The Bind Attribute lets you specify the exact properties a model binder should include in the binding.

Comment: It is commonly accepted that usage of the `[Bind]` functionality of MVC is an **anti-pattern**. The accepted solution is to use separate models to eliminate the risk of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_assignment_vulnerability instead of relying on convention of using Bind. It only takes 1 person to forget using Bind to inadvertently allow a person to exploit mass assignment.

Comment: Completely agree with @ChrisMarisic.  I would avoid using the `Bind` attribute and instead use separate models.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic - Looked at the wiki page and then followed a link from there to an article by Shay Friedman (AKA IronShay). He explained the problem with a simple example. Very helpful in understanding how it works. Thanks.